# Does the character of the body, ex. symmetrical top, sphrical top, depend on the origin chosen?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

Given a homogenous cube of length b and mass M. If we start with one of the vertex being the origin then the inertial tensor in this case is
$$
\{\textbf{I}\}=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3}\beta & -\frac{1}{4}\beta & -\frac{1}{4}\beta \\
-\frac{1}{4}\beta & \frac{2}{3}\beta & -\frac{1}{4}\beta \\
-\frac{1}{4}\beta & -\frac{1}{4}\beta & \frac{2}{3}\beta
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
where $\beta=Mb^2$. Then by diagonalization, we can find the **principal moment of inertia** to be
$$
\{\textbf{I}\}=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{1}{6}\beta & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{11}{12}\beta & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{11}{12}\beta
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
which implies that the cube in this case is a symmetrical top. However, if I move the origin to the center of mass $(\frac{b}{2}, \frac{b}{2}, \frac{b}{2})$, we can apply the **parallel axis-theorem** so that the inertial tensor in this case is
$$
\{\textbf{I}\}=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{1}{6}\beta & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{6}\beta & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}\beta
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
then it seems to imply the cube is a spherical top. But I find it strange since how one body can be described with two distinct characters. So there must be something that I understood wrongly in this case. Can anyone tell me what happens in here? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment of inertia of an object is a property of both the shape of the object and the axis it is rotating around. It is not an intrinsic property of the object.

The [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) says that you can find the moment of inertia of an object rotating around any axis once you know the moment of inertia around its center of mass. That means we are often interested in the moment of inertia of an object around axes passing through the center of mass, but it's not the only thing.

In the case of the cube, you've correctly calculated the moment of inertia of the cube around its center of mass. The parallel axis theorem says that the moment of inertia around a vertex is $I_{CM} + m(\vec{c}^2\mathbb{I}-\vec{c}\,\vec{c}^T)$ where $\vec{c} = \frac{b}{2}(-1,-1,-1)$. Calculating this out gives you your first expression.

**Moral:** Moment of inertia depends on both the shape of the object and the point or axis it is rotating around.

Comment: So for example, if I have fixed the vertex of the cube to be the origin and consider the origin of the body axes are also coincide with this point then any rotation in this manner is symmetrical top as shown in my post, i.e. I can think of symmetrical top as an intrinsic property of the rotation. Similarly, when the origin is moved to the center of mass then the rotation follows this manner is spherical top. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question. How's this: a cube rotating around its center of mass behaves just like a sphere rotating around its center of mass. A cube rotating around its vertex behaves just like a symmetrical top.

Comment: I understand that when the cube rotates around the vertex, it behaves like a symmetrical top. However, what I don't understand is that when the origin moves to the center of mass, the principal moment of inertial as I show previously are same such as $I_1=I_2=I_3$ which behaves as a spherical top.

Comment: I think I see. When people talk about moment of inertia the origin is almost always taken as the center of rotation. When you shift your origin you are also shifting the point of rotation, even if that's not what you originally meant.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean when taking the center of mass as origin, the principal moment of inertial will be equaled with respect to their associated principal axes, while it is not true when taking the corner as the origin. And you are right, when asking to compute the principal moment of inertial, it almost always assumes with respect to the center of mass. Anyway, thanks for the answer!